# home-assistant iframe with nodered not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, home-assistant

I have a raspberry pi3 with ubuntu and docker running the following containers

1. home-assistant
2. mosquitto
3. zigbee2mqtt
4. nodered

this is configured with the following docker-compose yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  homeassistant:
    container_name: hass
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    volumes:
      - ./hass/configuration.yaml:/config/configuration.yaml
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"

  nodered:
    container_name: nodered
    image: nodered/node-red
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - nodered_data:/data
    depends_on:
      - homeassistant
      - mosquitto
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Amsterdam"
    restart: unless-stopped

  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    volumes:
      - "./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config"
      - "mqtt_data:/mosquitto/data"
      - "./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log"
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam

  zigbee2mqtt:
      container_name: zigbee2mqtt
      image: koenkk/zigbee2mqtt
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - "./z2mqtt/data/configuration.yaml:/app/data/configuration.yaml"
        - "z2mqtt:/app/data"
      ports:
        # Frontend port
        - 8080:8080
      environment:
        - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
      devices:
      #  # Make sure this matched your adapter location
        - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyACM0"
      depends_on:
        - mosquitto

volumes:
  nodered_data:
  mqtt_data:
  z2mqtt:
```

I have a configuration.yaml for home-assistant with the following content

```
default_config:

panel_iframe:
  nodered:
    title: Node-Red
    icon: mdi:shuffle-variant
    url: "http://nodered:1880"
    require_admin: true
```

I can't get the iframe to connect with nodered for some reason.
I have tried connecting to the nodered container from an external system using the docker host ip and port 1880, and that works properly.
I also tried pinging the 'nodered' container from within the 'hass' container and that works also.

if I replace the iframe url with the docker host ip and port 1880 the iframe does work, however I would rather like to keep the connection within the internal docker network.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

*A little late, but for anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future:*

Since the URL inside the iframe is being loaded by your browser, **you need to specify an address which is reachable from outside the docker network**. Hence you cannot provide the service name as a domain name.